# When is a specific type actually a System.Object?

Tags: c#, wpf, types

In my WPF application, I have the following bit of code in an IValueConverter:

```
if (value.GetType().BaseType != typeof(Member))
    return string.Empty;
```

`Member` is an auto-generated Entity Framework object. When bound to a property of `List<Member>` it works as expected - the converter accepts this comparison and does not return.

I'm currently writing some unit tests for this part of the code. So I tested it with this:

```
MemberConverter conv = new MemberConverter();
Member mem = new Member{ MemberName = "Arnold" };
var result = conv.Convert((Member)mem, typeof(string), null, null);
```

And `result` comes back as `String.Empty`.

When I step through the code, it's the type comparison that's failing. My self-generated `mem` object has a `BaseType` of `System.Object`.

I can understand why the base type could come back has a plain old object. But I can't see why it's behaving differently in these two scenarios. Can someone explain, and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: every object is always a `System.Object`

Comment: The base type is an immediate type the given type inherits its members from. For a generated type deriving directly from `Member`, its base type is also `Member`. But if you pass an instance of `Member`, you'll ask the `Member` type what's its base type. And since all objects (_unusally_) inherit from `System.Object`, you'll get this type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity Framework is creating a dynamic type on the fly that has Member as a base type, overridding any virtual properties you supply to provide automatic 'lazy loading' magic.

You might consider doing this instead:

```
if (!typeof(Member).IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))
```

Or, even more directly, since you have an instance and not just a type

```
if (!(value is Member))
```